# Linq optimisation within a foreach

Tags: c#, linq, optimization, foreach

I have been looking for a way of splitting a `foreach` loop into multiple parts and came across the following code:

```
foreach(var item in items.Skip(currentPage * itemsPerPage).Take(itemsPerPage))
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Would `items.Skip(currentPage * itemsPerPage).Take(itemsPerPage)` be processed in every iteration, or would it be processed once, and have a temporary result used with the foreach loop automatically by the compiler?

Comment: Put a break point in and see.

Comment: That's only one split. Are you calling that from a loop too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The foreach construction is equivalent to:

```
IEnumerator enumerator = myCollection.GetEnumerator();
try
{
   while (enumerator.MoveNext())
   {
       object current = enumerator.Current;
       Console.WriteLine(current);
   }
}
finally
{
   IDisposable e = enumerator as IDisposable;
   if (e != null)
   {
       e.Dispose();
   }
}
```

So, no, `myCollection` would be processed only once.

**Update:**

Please note that this depends on the implementation of the `IEnumerator` that the `IEnumerable` uses.

In this (evil) example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;


namespace TestStack
{
    class EvilEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T> {

        private IEnumerable<T> enumerable;
        private int index = -1;

        public EvilEnumerator(IEnumerable<T> e) 
        {
            enumerable = e;
        }


        #region IEnumerator<T> Membres

        public T Current
        {
            get { return enumerable.ElementAt(index); }
        }

        #endregion

        #region IDisposable Membres

        public void Dispose()
        {

        }

        #endregion

        #region IEnumerator Membres

        object IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get { return enumerable.ElementAt(index); }
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            index++;
            if (index >= enumerable.Count())
                return false;
            return true;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {

        }

        #endregion
    }
    class DemoEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {

        private IEnumerable<T> enumerable;

        public DemoEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> e)
        {
            enumerable = e; 
        }


        #region IEnumerable<T> Membres

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new EvilEnumerator<T>(enumerable);
        }

        #endregion

        #region IEnumerable Membres

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.GetEnumerator();
        }

        #endregion
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IEnumerable<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(0,100);
            DemoEnumerable<int> enumerable = new DemoEnumerable<int>(numbers);
            foreach (var item in enumerable)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Each iteration over `enumerable` would evaluate `numbers` two times.

Answer (score 9):

No, it would be processed once.

It's the same like:

```
public IEnumerable<Something> GetData() {
    return someData; 
}


foreach(var d in GetData()) {
   //do something with [d]
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is correct. I mean your GetData function is similar to a getter only property, and each time the loop increments its step, will call that get accessor, or in your case your method, basically calling the Skip / Take construction on each step.

Comment: @PotecaruTudor: in foreach loop, it will be called ones. To prove that, just make a simple test.

Comment: Yep, just debugged a test example and you were right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Question:

> Would items.Skip(currentPage * itemsPerPage).Take(itemsPerPage) be
>   processed every iteration, or would it be processed once, and have a
>   temporary result used with the foreach loop automatically by the
>   compiler?

Answer:

It would be processed once, not every iteration. You can put the collection into a variable to make the foreach more readable. Illustrated below.

```
foreach(var item in items.Skip(currentPage * itemsPerPage).Take(itemsPerPage))
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

vs.

```
List<MyClass> query = items.Skip(currentPage * itemsPerPage).Take(itemsPerPage).ToList();

foreach(var item in query)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

vs.

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> query = items.Skip(currentPage * itemsPerPage).Take(itemsPerPage);

foreach(var item in query)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that you present will only iterate the items in the list once, as others have pointed out.

However, that only gives you the items for one page. If you are handling multiple pages, you must be calling that code once for each page (because somewhere you must be incrementing `currentPage`, right?).

What I mean is that you must be doing something like this:

```
for (int currentPage = 0; currentPage < numPages; ++currentPage)
{
    foreach (var item in items.Skip(currentPage*itemsPerPage).Take(itemsPerPage))
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Now if you do *that*, then you *will* be iterating the sequence multiple times - once for each page. The first iteration will only go as far as the end of the first page, but the next will iterate from the beginning to the end of the second page (via the `Skip()` and the `Take()`) - and the next will iterate from the beginning to the end of the third page. And so on.

To avoid that you can write an extension method for `IEnumerable<T>` which partitions the data into batches (which you could also describe as "paginating" the data into "pages").

Rather than just presenting an IEnumerable of IEnumerables, it can be more useful to wrap each batch in a class to supply the batch index along with the items in the batch, like so:

```
public sealed class Batch<T>
{
    public readonly int Index;
    public readonly IEnumerable<T> Items;

    public Batch(int index, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        Index = index;
        Items = items;
    }
}

public static class EnumerableExt
{
    // Note: Not threadsafe, so not suitable for use with Parallel.Foreach() or IEnumerable.AsParallel()

    public static IEnumerable<Batch<T>> Partition<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input, int batchSize)
    {
        var enumerator = input.GetEnumerator();
        int index = 0;

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            yield return new Batch<T>(index++, nextBatch(enumerator, batchSize));
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> nextBatch<T>(IEnumerator<T> enumerator, int blockSize)
    {
        do { yield return enumerator.Current; }
        while (--blockSize > 0 && enumerator.MoveNext());
    }
}
```

This extension method does not buffer the data, and it only iterates through it once.

Given this extension method, it becomes more readable to batch up the items. Note that this example enumerates through ALL items for all pages, unlike the OP's example which only iterates through the items for one page:

```
var items = Enumerable.Range(10, 50); // Pretend we have 50 items.
int itemsPerPage = 20;

foreach (var page in items.Partition(itemsPerPage))
{
    Console.Write("Page " + page.Index + " items: ");

    foreach (var i in page.Items)
        Console.Write(i + " ");

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```